# NoneType error when using cv2.HoughLinesP function put by images

Tags: python, video-streaming, python-3.5, opencv

First of all I am putting values into hough_lines such as `rho = 2, theta = np.pi/180, threshold = 15, min_line_len = 40 , max_line_gap = 20 
lines = hough_lines(masked_edges, rho, theta, threshold, min_line_len, max_line_gap)`

```
def hough_lines(img, rho, theta, threshold, min_line_len, max_line_gap):

    #This function is used for drawing line when we give a specific criteria into the pixels we want to pick up.
    #This function is used with draw_lines function to draw the lines in specific pixels 
    #which are drawn by region_of_interest function. 


    """`img` should be the output of a Canny transform.

    Returns an image with hough lines drawn.
    """


    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), minLineLength=min_line_len, maxLineGap=max_line_gap)

    line_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    draw_lines(line_img, lines)

    return line_img
```

Above is my code and getting following error.

```
  File "auto.py", line 68, in <module>
    output = lane.process_image(frame)
  File "/home/pi/test/lane.py", line 227, in process_image
    lines = hough_lines(masked_edges, rho, theta, threshold, min_line_len, max_line_gap)
  File "/home/pi/test/lane.py", line 154, in hough_lines
    draw_lines(line_img, lines)
  File "/home/pi/test/lane.py", line 97, in draw_lines
    for line in lines:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

In the main function, I am trying to put the frame taken by video capture into process_image function in lane file.

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    print('Succeed to connect...')
    data = ''
    data=sys.stdin.read(1)[0]

    print("data input=",data)
    while True:

        if not cam.isOpened():
           print("Wait for the header")

        else:
           flag, frame = cam.read()
           frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
           cv2.imshow('video', frame)
           #print(type(frame))

        output = lane.process_image(frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           exit()
```

I tried many things such that I changed parameter values for hough_lines function and tried to see what functions affects NoneType value in terms of image. However, before `cv2.HoughLinesP` function, every function has their own value with narray type.

--edit

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
import os

def grayscale(img): # It converts the original picture to the gray scale picture.

    """Applies the Grayscale transform
    This will return an image with only one color channel
    but NOTE: to see the returned image as grayscale
    (assuming your grayscaled image is called 'gray')
    you should call plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')"""
    return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    # Or use BGR2GRAY if you read an image with cv2.imread()
    # return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def canny(img, low_threshold, high_threshold): 

    #After applied grayscale function, it converts the grayscale image to edges
    #which is a binary image with white pixels. 

    """Applies the Canny transform"""
    return cv2.Canny(img, low_threshold, high_threshold)

def gaussian_blur(img, kernel_size):

    #Gaussian blur is applied for suppressing noise and nonlogical gradients by averaging. 
    """Applies a Gaussian Noise kernel"""
    return cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (kernel_size, kernel_size), 0)

def region_of_interest(img, vertices):
    # This functions is used for tracing a specific line of the road
    # utilizing vertices which is are 4 integer points here and ignore_mask_color which ignores 
    # pixels if those do not meet the criteria. 
    """
    Applies an image mask.

    Only keeps the region of the image defined by the polygon
    formed from `vertices`. The rest of the image is set to black.
    `vertices` should be a numpy array of integer points.
    """
    #defining a blank mask to start with
    mask = np.zeros_like(img)   

    #defining a 3 channel or 1 channel color to fill the mask with depending on the input image
    if len(img.shape) > 2:
        channel_count = img.shape[2]  # i.e. 3 or 4 depending on your image
        ignore_mask_color = (255,) * channel_count
    else:
        ignore_mask_color = 255

    #filling pixels inside the polygon defined by "vertices" with the fill color    
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, vertices, ignore_mask_color)

    #returning the image only where mask pixels are nonzero
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)
    return masked_image


def draw_lines(img, lines, color=[255, 0, 0], thickness=2):
    """
    NOTE: this is the function you might want to use as a starting point once you want to 
    average/extrapolate the line segments you detect to map out the full
    extent of the lane (going from the result shown in raw-lines-example.mp4
    to that shown in P1_example.mp4).  

    Think about things like separating line segments by their 
    slope ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)) to decide which segments are part of the left
    line vs. the right line.  Then, you can average the position of each of 
    the lines and extrapolate to the top and bottom of the lane.

    This function draws `lines` with `color` and `thickness`.    
    Lines are drawn on the image inplace (mutates the image).
    If you want to make the lines semi-transparent, think about combining
    this function with the weighted_img() function below
    """
    """
    for line in lines:
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
            cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, thickness)
    """        
    right_slopes = []
    right_intercepts = []
    left_slopes = []
    left_intercepts = []
    left_points_x = []
    left_points_y = []
    right_points_x = []
    right_points_y = []

    y_max = img.shape[0]
    y_min = img.shape[0]

    for line in lines:
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
            slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

            if slope < 0.0 and slope > -math.inf: # math.inf = floating point positive infinity
                left_slopes.append(slope) # left line
                left_points_x.append(x1)
                left_points_x.append(x2)
                left_points_y.append(y1)
                left_points_y.append(y2)
                left_intercepts.append(y1 - slope*x1)

            if slope > 0.0 and slope < math.inf:
                right_slopes.append(slope) # right line
                right_points_x.append(x1)
                right_points_x.append(x2)
                right_points_y.append(y1)
                right_points_y.append(y2)
                right_intercepts.append(y1 - slope*x1)

            y_min = min(y1,y2,y_min)



    if len(left_slopes) > 0:
        left_slope = np.mean(left_slopes)
        left_intercept = np.mean(left_intercepts)
        x_min_left = int((y_min - left_intercept)/left_slope) 
        x_max_left = int((y_max - left_intercept)/left_slope)
        cv2.line(img, (x_min_left, y_min), (x_max_left, y_max), [255, 0, 0], 8)

    if len(right_slopes) > 0:
        right_slope = np.mean(right_slopes)
        right_intercept = np.mean(right_intercepts)
        x_min_right = int((y_min - right_intercept)/right_slope) 
        x_max_right = int((y_max - right_intercept)/right_slope)
        cv2.line(img, (x_min_right, y_min), (x_max_right, y_max), [255, 0, 0], 8)


def hough_lines(img, rho, theta, threshold, min_line_len, max_line_gap):

    #This function is used for drawing line when we give a specific criteria into the pixels we want to pick up.
    #This function is used with draw_lines function to draw the lines in specific pixels 
    #which are drawn by region_of_interest function. 

    """
    `img` should be the output of a Canny transform.

    Returns an image with hough lines drawn.
    """
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), minLineLength=min_line_len, maxLineGap=max_line_gap)
    line_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    draw_lines(line_img, lines)
    return line_img

# Python 3 has support for cool math symbols.

def weighted_img(img, initial_img, α=0.8, β=1., γ=0.):
    # By appliying "color" binary image, it finally draws the line on the edge image.

    """
    `img` is the output of the hough_lines(), An image with lines drawn on it.
    Should be a blank image (all black) with lines drawn on it.

    `initial_img` should be the image before any processing.

    The result image is computed as follows:

    initial_img * α + img * β + γ
    NOTE: initial_img and img must be the same shape!
    """
    return cv2.addWeighted(initial_img, α, img, β, γ)

def process_image(image):
    # NOTE: The output you return should be a color image (3 channel) for processing video below
    # TODO: put your pipeline here,
    # you should return the final output (image where lines are drawn on lanes)

    # Read in and grayscale the image
    gray = grayscale(image)


    # Define a kernel size and apply Gaussian smoothing
    kernel_size = 5
    blur_gray = gaussian_blur(gray, kernel_size)


    # Define our parameters for Canny and apply
    low_threshold = 50
    high_threshold = 150
    edges = canny(blur_gray, low_threshold, high_threshold)


    # Next we'll create a masked edges image using cv2.fillPoly()
    imshape = image.shape
    vertices = np.array([[(120,imshape[0]),(450, 320), (500, 320), (imshape[1],imshape[0])]], dtype=np.int32)
    masked_edges = region_of_interest(edges, vertices)



    # Define the Hough transform parameters
    # Make a blank the same size as our image to draw on
    rho = 2 # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
    theta = np.pi/180 # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
    threshold = 15 # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
    min_line_len = 40 # minimum number of pixels making up a line
    max_line_gap = 20 # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments
    line_image = np.copy(image)*1 #creating a blank to draw lines on


    # Run Hough on edge detected image
    lines = hough_lines(masked_edges, rho, theta, threshold, min_line_len, max_line_gap)


    # Create a "color" binary image to combine with line image
    color_edges = np.dstack((edges, edges, edges)) 


    # Draw the lines on the edge image
    lines_edges = weighted_img(lines, line_image)

    return lines_edges
```

Comment: Your code is calling `draw_lines` with the lines list. Please share the code of `draw_lines`. It looks like the `lines` you are passing to the function is None so the loop `for line in lines` throws the exception

Comment: @balderman Oh, I edited and added draw_lines function.

Comment: OK. If we agree that the issue is in `for line in lines` , please add code before the loop the looks like `if not lines: print('lines is None or empty') return`. If you see this print it means that the lines you use is None or empty and you should try and understand why.

Comment: Oh I got this error. OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in arithm_op, file /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 659

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto.py", line 68, in <module>
    output = lane.process_image(frame)
  File "/home/pi/test/lane.py", line 238, in process_image
    lines_edges = weighted_img(lines, line_image)
  File "/home/pi/test/lane.py", line 176, in weighted_img
    return cv2.addWeighted(initial_img, α, img, β, γ)
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op

Comment: Please explain the changes you did to the code.

Comment: Like you suggested me, I put this line :   
    `if not lines: 
       print('lines is None or empty') 
       return`

Comment: Do you see the print message in the console?

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry I didn't tell you about it. `lines is None or empty
OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in arithm_op, file /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 659` Above is an exact error message

Comment: Since we have proved that lines is None, you need to go back to the caller code and understand why it is None. The caller code is ` hough_lines` and the `lines` are returned by `cv2.HoughLinesP(...)`. You should try to understand why it returns None.

Comment: Hmm yes that's my question actually since I've been trying to figure why it returns null when using cv2.HoughLinesP() function..

Comment: Thank you though. Let me figure it out more.